# Rest Assured Json Path returns Exception

Tags: rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I´m reading json from a file in order to compare it to an http request body´s json.

I´m doing

```
JsonPath expectedJson = new JsonPath(new File("response.json"));
// some more code
assertThat().body("", equalTo(expectedJson.getMap("")));
```

which results in `JsonPathException: Failed to parse the JSON document`

This is the `response.json` file, which I copied from the response in Postman:

```
{
  "screenDefinition":{
    "taskId":"account-type",
    "parameters":null
  },
  "prospect":{
    "initializationType":"FIRST_HOLDER",
    "jointAccount":{
      "jointAccountId":655
    },
    "emailConfirmed":false,
    "addressConfirmed":false,
    "emailValidated":false,
    "smsCodeAttemptsLeft":0,
    "mobilePhoneValidated":false,
    "paragraphsAccepted":false,
    "termsConditionsAccepted":false,
    "changedToAutonomousMethod":false,
    "changedToIdentificationMethod":false,
    "contractAccepted":false,
    "prospectOnboardContactType":"NONE",
    "secondAccountHolder":false,
    "evidencesUploaded":false,
    "uploadEvidencesLater":false
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `JsonPathException` you got is probably caused by `java.io.FileNotFoundException` which means that path to your file is incorrect.
Try checking if file exists first:

```
File file = new File("response.json");
System.out.println("File exists: " + file.exists());
JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(file);
```